# NSMutableArray always empty

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

```
NSMutableArray *experienceValues;
experienceValues = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:0,83,174,276,nil];

NSLog(@"%@", [experienceValues objectAtIndex:3]);
```

Why does this always throw `-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds for empty array` when it is clearly allocated and initialised in the line just before?

Comment: You're question has already been well answered, but do you not receive any warnings or errors at line 2?

Comment: First off why not make lines 1 and 2 just one line? Second your missing a `[` on line 2 just before `[NSMutableArray all...`, and finally you need `@` before each integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap integer values like `@0, @83, @174, ...`, as primitive integers are no objects.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The NSMutableArray class as most of the collection classes in cocoa, accepts only objects. So if you want to put numbers, you can't put primitive type, but only instances of `NSNumber` class, thus:

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]...etc
```

Or with literals:

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@0,@83,@174,@276.. etc
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, but i cant accept any of the answers for 8 more minutes

Comment: No big deal, you are welcome. I'd like also to point out that when you get a value back as you'd like, you get an NSnumber object, so you can't do "math operation" on it. So [[experienceValues objectAtIndex:3]intValue] will return the correct primitive type.

Comment: Remark: `@0, @83` are "NSNumber literals". "Subscripting" is e.g. `array[0]` or `dict[@"key"]`.

Answer (score 2):

The array is empty because the arguments are nil terminated and 0 is interpreted as nil.

The array should only contain objects (as opposed to primitives like ints). In you case you should create NSNumbers for all the numbers. You can do that with the number literal syntax `@2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C collection classes can only store objects; not primitives like `int`.

You need to wrap them in [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) objects.

If these are literal values then the answer provided by @Kirsteins demonstrates the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSMutableArray *experienceValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@0,@83,@174,@276,......., nil];

NSLog(@"%d", [experienceValues objectAtIndex:3]);
```

As `initWithObjects:` accepts only object you need to put only objects in it

Comment: I think @0 (NSNumber) would be better than @"0" (NSString)

Comment: Thanks for advice and yes it is sure better :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add integer value to NSArray.

```
NSMutableArray *experienceValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:42],nil];
```

then convert it back to integer like,

```
NSLog(@"%@", [experienceValues objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: Here you are adding strings, rather than NSNumber literals

Comment: @c.cam108..yes,thats not the ideal way to do..i agree with u and do apolozige for the old method of adding strings and then converting it to integer...so edited the answer..